# Is there a list for blender build-in attributes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there anywhere that we could look up the list of build-in attributes on an mesh or object?

for example the object origin?

*for use in geometry nodes.*

Comment: I thought this question was a duplicate but it's more specific on "list of all build-in attributes" so far I know location rotation scale and normal.

Comment: This will be fleshed out once the project is officially in the tracks. I'm sure there will be more information in the official doc, or even in the "spreadsheet" project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be an attribute search included in blender soon.

source: Blender daily
( https://youtu.be/4pPSsAuM8sQ )

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is what you're after. Keep track of that page as the project progresses:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html

Comment: I read that page it's missing stuff, "normal" for example is one of them. (on 2/25/2021)
but thanks I'll keep track of it.